# Python function: multiple arguments

Tags: python, function, arguments

I need to define a function T(i) which has the same value (say 10) from i=1 to 1=3, and a different value (say 20) at i=4. I wrote the following code,

```
def T(i):
for i in range(1, 4):
    y= 10
    return y
if i==4:
    y= 20
    return y

for i in range(1, 5): print(i,T(i))
```

Values from i=1 to 1=3 are printed correctly, but the value at i=4 is wrong. Seems like the second argument is not assigned correctly. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `if` block after the `for` is unreachable. The first `return` hands over control to the caller. What exactly are you up to?

Comment: Your indentation (or lackof) is incorrect, maybe that's the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ILI, but the indentation is correct in the original code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Moses, but how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the special case handled first

```
def T(i):
  if i < 4:
    return 10
  else:
    return 20

for i in range(1, 5): print(i,T(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for the `for` loop in the function, as you call `T()` from a loop  anyway, and `return` will exit the function, so the `if` statement cannot execute.

An easier way to do this is:

```
def T(i):
    return 20 if i==4 else 10
```

However, defining a function is not necessary to accomplish this, you could implement the same condition in a list comprehension:

```
[20 if i==4 else 10 for i in range(1,5)]
```